# Backend for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I had a question about building a website. The website is for looking at house floor plans and being able to search a database for specific floor plans. (i.e. 3 bedroom 2 baths). I want to use firebase as my DB. To make this possible would I have to use Node or would I be able to just use React to make calls to the database. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The question is if you can use the Firebase API/SDK to make all your queries on the client side. If not this is a sign that you need an extra layer in a form of a server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems that Firebase can do most of what I would want.

Comment: Then you don't need it. If you are doing heavy calculations on the client side you could consider using a server to reduce the load on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

React is not a database library/framework and therefor has no support for doing these calls. I would go by backing your app (which may also be a public web app) by some kind of server.

You could use a lightweight `express` server that exposes your API and call it
with something like `axios`, `window.fetch` or so from the client.

You might want to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript) related question.